# How to add control to the TRzToolbar

Tags: delphi

I have add TRzToolbar to the form. I want it to look like as shown in figure below.

[image]

I want to add control as shown in figure to the TRzToolbar..I right clicked TRzToolbar component on the form selected edit toolbar which bring in Toolbar editor with stock images as shown below.

[image]

In stock images it is not showing control like checkbox,drop down and radio button etc as shown in first figure.  How to add these control to TRzToolbar?

Comment: It's just the same as a standard TToolbar. Treat the control as a container and add children just as you would add children to a panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Toolbar Editor can only handle Toolbuttons. Instead using the editor, simply drop the desired control from the tool palette onto the Toolbar in the form designer.